# Correct Form of the Fokker-Planck Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, physics, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Derive the Fokker-Planck equation by requiring conservation of probability:
$$\int_{\partial V}\mathbf{J}\cdot\mathbf{dS}=-\frac{d}{dt}\int_{V}p(\mathbf{r},t)dV$$
The flux can be written as a sum of convective and diffusive terms
$$\mathbf{J}=p(\mathbf{r},t)\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r},t)-D(\mathbf{r},t)\mathbf{∇}p(\mathbf{r},t)$$
and substitution of this with use of the divergence theorem yields
$$\partial_{t}p(x,t)=-\partial_{x}[p(x,t)v(x,t)]+\partial_{x}[D(x,t)\partial_{x
}p(x,t)]$$
where I have moved to one dimension for simplicity.

However the form found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)
is given as
$$\partial_{t}p(x,t)=-\partial_{x}[p(x,t)v(x,t)]+\partial_{x}^2[D(x,t)p(x,t)]$$
which differs slightly in the second term.

Essentially the issue is that Fick's law, $$\mathbf{J}_{\textrm{diffusive}}=-D(\mathbf{r},t)\nabla p(\mathbf{r},t)$$ disagrees with the derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation used on wikipedia (which starts from the Langevin equation).

Does anyone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression for the Fick's law is correct,
$$
\mathbf{J}_{\textrm{diffusive}}=-D(\mathbf{r},t)\nabla P(\mathbf{r},t) \, ,
$$
and the minus is correct as well.

In general,

$$
\partial_t P = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}
$$

where
$$
\mathbf{J} = \mathbf{v} P  - D \nabla P
$$

so that
$$
\partial_t P = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = - div (\mathbf{v} P) + \nabla D \cdot \nabla P + D \nabla^2 P 
$$

is the usual Fokker Planck equation.